# Mod-Rewrite loading files behind the DocumentRoot

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` to point to files that reside behind the DocumentRoot. My folder structure looks like this:

```
home/
    webroot/
    other_files/
```

I have a `.htaccess` file in webroot with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/other_files/$1
```

If I try to access http://example.com/file.html I receive the following error:

> The requested URL /home/other_files/file.html was not found on this server.

Is it even possible to load files that are behind the DocumentRoot? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you need to add a section with

```
<Directory "/home/other_files">
  (options)
</Directory>
```

to your server configuration before apache will be able to serve anything from it.  For an example, my DocumentRoot is /var/www but there is this section in the default available site:

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

You could then rewrite a URL to go to /doc/ and the server would know where to get the files from.

Comment: I tried Alias to a directory outside DocumentRoot without a <Directory> section and it worked...

Comment: @Pere You would need to _grant_ access to the "directory outside DocumentRoot" _somewhere_. If you did not have to explicitly include a `<Directory>` section for that directory then it's possible you already have `<Directory>` section elsewhere in the config that grants access to a parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know why that rule doesn't work:

The reason that it isn't able to rewrite to `/home/other_files/file.html` is that mod_rewrite is parsing the path as `/home/webroot/home/other_files/file.html` since from mod_rewrite's point of view the preceding slash is equivalent to your document root of `/home/webroot`.

[Ryan Ahearn's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441/mod-rewrite-loading-files-behind-the-documentroot#8454) is a decent one, and is likely the route you want to go.

Comment: "mod_rewrite is parsing the path as `/home/webroot/home/other_files/file.html`" - Yes. _Unless_ the rule is defined in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context (ie. not `.htaccess`) in which case it will accept an absolute filesystem path as well (as a root-relative URl-path).

Answer (score 1):

The credit goes to Ryan Aheam, but I'm going to spell it out. I'm a beginner and even with Ryan's answer I had to experiment with a few things to get the syntax right.

I wanted my `DocumentRoot` to be my `cakephp` directory. But then I had a Mantis Bug tracker that was just regular PHP and so not in the `cakephp` directory.  The the files below I have the following working.

`http://www.example.com` : served by  `/var/www/cakephp`

`http://www.example.com/mantisbt` : served by `/var/www/html/mantisbt`

File `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
Alias /mantisbt/ "/var/www/html/mantisbt/"                                                                          
<Directory "/var/www/html/">                                                                                        
    AllowOverride All                                                                                               
</Directory>                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                    
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                  
    ServerAdmin me@my_email.com                                                                             
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cakephp                                                                                   
    ServerName my_website.com                                                                                      
    <Directory /var/www/cakephp/>                                                                                   
        AllowOverride All                                                                                           
    </Directory>                                                                                                    
</VirtualHost>
```

File `/var/www/cakephp/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^mantisbt/?$   /mantisbt/  [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "I'm going to spell it out" - although you would have also needed to have granted access to the areas (outside the document root) that are the target of the `Alias` (as Ryan is doing in his answer, albeit for Apache 2.2). You may have done this for a parent directory, although it would be preferable to do this just for the directories in question. Also, unless `/mantisbt` is accessed from multiple vHosts then it would be preferable to have these directives in the relevant vHost config, rather than being "global" in the _server_ config.