# Serving a directory outside DocumentRoot with Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want `exampleapp.com/clientapp/` to execute the index.php in `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp`.

This stackoverflow question outlines something similar to what I want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454/173630

I'm having some trouble getting this working. Here's the start of my VirtualHost setup:

```
<VirtualHost exampleapp.com:80>

DocumentRoot /home/platform/src/serverapp/public

RewriteEngine On

Alias /clientapp/ "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp">
    FallbackResource index.php
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

RewriteRule ^/clientapp/(.*)$ /clientapp/$1 [PT]
```

I'm using Apache 2.2.22. I know this is kind of a confusing setup -- the reason I'm doing this is to avoid cross-domain AJAX requests from clientapp to serverapp.

With this configuration I'm not getting any errors, it's just falling through to the server app.

**Update**
The problem was that I had a BasicAuth set up on `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp`, and the password wasn't being prompted for when visiting `exampleapp.com/clientapp/` and it was just silently failing. I took off the BasicAuth for now, which gets it to work.

Comment: @JonLin No errors, it's just falling through to serverapp/public

Comment: Why do you have the `RewriteRule` at the bottom? The `Alias` should be sufficient.

Comment: @JonLin thanks for the tip - I'm new to apache configuration. I've removed the RewriteRule - same behavior so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few things out, it looks like this is just mod_alias being retarded and either blindly mashing together file-path and URI-path or mistaking the file-path (`/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp`) for a URI-path (not sure how). Either way, you can do one of two things, it looks like.

1. Add a trailing slash to your file-path:

   ```
   Alias /clientapp/ "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp/"
   ```
2. Remove the trailing slash from your URI-path:

   ```
   Alias /clientapp "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/clientapp"
   ```

Both seems to do the trick, but I would suggest doing the second option, as it would match requests for `exampleapp.com/clientapp` (no trailing slash), and mod_dir will properly recognize it as a directory and redirect you to `exampleapp.com/clientapp/`. Whereas if you go with first option, going to `exampleapp.com/clientapp` would just give you a 404 (or something in the document root ends up handling it).

Answer (score 0):

Change `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` to `<Location /clientapp>...</Location>` and keep everything inside it.