# How can you configure Apache to run CakePhP and raw PHP Apps as separate virtual hosts running side-by-side on the same server?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, httpd.conf

On my CentOS Linux VPS I have full LAMP installed.  I have a CakePHP website (and intend to add a few more) as a virtual host.  I also have a web based bug tracker called MantisBT that is implemented in PHP.  I'd like to set up my Apache configuration file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) to index both side-by-side.  My websites are not in DNS.  I access them using the raw IP number.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/var/www/
    MyCakePhPApp/

    html/
       mantisbt/
```

Here's what I have in my httpd.conf file:

```
# This makes my MantisBT work under http:/<my_ip>/mantisbt    
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html                                                                                      

# This makes my CakePhP work under http:/<my_ip>                                                                                                                          
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                       
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tecadmin.net                                                                                   
    ServerName example.com                                                                                        
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyCakePhPApp                                                                                      
    <Directory /var/www/MyCakePhPApp>                                                                                       
          Allowoverride All                                                                                              
    </Directory>                                                                                                         
</VirtualHost>
```

With this my CakePhP is accessible as "http:/my_ip" but my mantisbt site is not accessible.  "http:/my_ip/mantisbt" goes to CakePhP and says that controller is missing.  If I comment out the entire VirtualHost, then Mantis is indeed accessible as: "http:/my_ip/mantisbt", but of course then my CakePHP site is not accessible.

Does anyone know how to get both these websites working side-by-side?

Comment: You can make your document root /var/www
then access to your cakephp aplication as http:/my_ip/MyCakePhPApp

Comment: This is answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441/mod-rewrite-loading-files-behind-the-documentroot/32534645#32534645